# Deinstalling application data. Which path to use in uninstaller?

Tags: deployment, installation, nsis

I am creating an installer using [nsis](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page). The application downloads a huge amount of user data. What is the best way to remove this data in uninstaller?

1. Set the application data path in
   installer (using
   environment/registry, config file
   etc) and use it in application?
2. Use fixed path in both installer and application.
3. Something else ...?

How do you solve this?

Comment: When you say user data, does that mean you store it in AppData?

Answer (score 0):

I use the application data path from Windows ("$APPDATA\Application Name") for the data when installing/uninstalling, then delete the directory when uninstalling.